# How to call EXPECT_CALL gtest macro before the object construction

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a class that calls a mocked function in the initializer list.
I want to use EXPECT_CALL in order to verify that the mocked function is called only once.
The problem is that I can't use the macro before the constructor because it's the first function that runs, neither after it because the mocked function is called in the constructor.

For example:
*ui.cpp*

```
class UI {
  public:
    UI() = default;
    ~UI() = default;

    virtual std::string get_name() {
        std::string name;
        std::cin >> name;
        return name;
    }
};
```

*foo.cpp*

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(UI& ui) : m_name(ui.get_name()) {}
    ~Foo() = default;
};
```

*mock_ui.hpp*

```
class MockUI : public UI {
    MockUI() : UI() = default;
    ~MockUI() = default;

    MOCK_METHOD(std::string, get_name, (), (override));
};
```

The problem occurs here:
*foo_test.cpp*

```
class FooTest : ::testing::Test {
  public:
    // I want to call EXPECT_CALL(m_ui, get_name()) before this line executes.
    FooTest() : m_foo(MockUI()) {}
    ~FooTest() = default;

  protected:
    void SetUp() override {}
    void TearDown() override {}

    Foo m_foo;
    MockUI m_ui;
};
```

I tried initializing the `Foo` object in the `SetUp()` function, but Foo doesn't have default constructor so it has to be initialized in the `FooTest` constructor.

**The Solution?**
The only idea I have is to call `EXPECT_CALL()` in MockUI constructor like this:
*mock_ui.hpp*

```
class MockUI : public UI {
    MockUI() : UI() {
        EXPECT_CALL(*this, get_name());
    }
    ~MockUI() = default;
    
    MOCK_METHOD(std::string, get_name, (), (override);
};
```

The problem is that I might use MockUI without calling `get_name()` or calling it multiple times, but this is the best solution I have.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Regardless of the possibility of `EXPECT_CALL` in the constructor, the shown code is not well designed. The object should not care of if its methods are called.

Comment: Can you provide MCVE? Here is [godbolt starting point](https://godbolt.org/z/hhTjs7Pfe). What is a code under test?

Comment: Also I see you inject dependency it  wrong way (pass by value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer initialization of `Foo` by using a pointer:

```
class FooTest : ::testing::Test {
public:
    FooTest() 
    { 
        EXPECT_CALL(m_ui, get_name()); 
        m_foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(m_ui); 
    }
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> m_foo;
    MockUI m_ui;
};
```

Or by adding a parent class that will initialize `MockUI` first:

```
class FooTestHelper: public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    FooTestHelper() { EXPECT_CALL(m_ui, get_name()); }
protected:
    MockUI m_ui;
};

class FooTest : public FooTestHelper
{
public:
    FooTest(): FooTestHelper{}, m_foo{m_ui} {}
private:
    Foo m_foo;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add EXPECT_CALL in initialization of dummy variable:

```
class FooTest : ::testing::Test {
  public:
    FooTest() {}
    ~FooTest() = default;

  protected:
    void SetUp() override {}
    void TearDown() override {}

    MockUI m_ui;
    bool dummy = (EXPECT_CALL(m_ui, get_name()), true);
    Foo m_foo{m_ui};
};
```

I moved initialization of `m_foo`, but it just for better visibility of order of initialization, you can left it in constructor.

Comment: This is a nice solution! Also you can use expectation dummy = EXPECT_CALL() and then check that it is called before other functions with After().